# Primefaces photoCam component not rendering

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces photoCam component exactly as explained in 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/photoCam.xhtml . unfortunately, unlike in the showcase my photoCam example, mine does not render. I have tried it on Firefox and Chrome the code is as follows:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form>  
<h:panelGrid columns="3">  
    <p:photoCam widgetVar="pc" listener="#{photoCamBean.oncapture}" update="photos"/>  

    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Capture" onclick="pc.capture()"/>  

    <p:imageSwitch effect="zoom" id="photos">  
        <ui:repeat value="#{photoCamBean.photos}" var="photo">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/photocam/#{photo}.png" />  
        </ui:repeat>  
    </p:imageSwitch>  
</h:panelGrid>  
</h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

And the bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PhotoCamBean {  

private List<String> photos = new ArrayList<String>();

private String getRandomImageName() {
            int i = (int) (Math.random() * 10000000);

            return String.valueOf(i);
    }

public List<String> getPhotos() {
    return photos;
}    

public void oncapture(CaptureEvent captureEvent) {
    String photo = getRandomImageName();
    this.photos.add(0,photo);
    byte[] data = captureEvent.getData();

            ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
            String newFileName = servletContext.getRealPath("") + File.separator + "photocam" + File.separator + photo + ".png";

            FileImageOutputStream imageOutput;
            try {
                    imageOutput = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(newFileName));
                    imageOutput.write(data, 0, data.length);
                    imageOutput.close();
            }
    catch(Exception e) {
                    throw new FacesException("Error in writing captured image.");
            }
}
```

}

The primefaces showcase photoCam renders a canvas with an adobe flash confirmation window but mine doesn't, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the meta tag in the head section of the page solves the problem as shown:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>

<h:form>  
<h:panelGrid columns="3">  
<p:photoCam widgetVar="pc" listener="#{photoCamBean.oncapture}" update="photos"/>  

<p:commandButton type="button" value="Capture" onclick="pc.capture()"/>  

<p:imageSwitch effect="zoom" id="photos">  
    <ui:repeat value="#{photoCamBean.photos}" var="photo">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/photocam/#{photo}.png" />  
    </ui:repeat>  
</p:imageSwitch>  
</h:panelGrid>  
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

I was able to view the canvas with an adobe flash confirmation window simply by adding the meta tag. Thank you all for your contribution.